# What do "promise of tomorrow" and "rug merchant" mean?

Tags: translation, comprehension

Here is the main text including the questioned parts.
*ps: this is a political statement.*

> As we proceed we cannot be **gulled by promises of what will happen tomorrow**—at bottom they really are **rug merchants**.

Comment: These are two different things. You're better off asking what this sentence means. Please also provide more context.

Comment: For example: "I promise that I will deliver tomorrow." Don't be gulled by that promise – pay *after* you have received the goods.

Comment: In this setting, a promise of tomorrow implies an empty promise, and rug merchants implies *used car salesmen*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - I would have guessed toupee salesman.

Comment: What @YosefBaskin said. So far as I'm aware, "rug merchant" has no currency among mainstream Anglophones for what looks like some *other* culture's equivalent of Anglophone ***used car salesman*** (perhaps ***estate agent*** in BrE,  ***snake oil salesman*** in AmE) - basically, an archetypal ["dodgy dealer".](https://www.crosswordsolver.org/clues/d/dodgy-dealer.365968#:~:text=a%20person%20without%20employment%20who,and%20having%20a%20good%20time)

Comment: I actually bought a rug in my travels from a merchant who said it "took a family [of my faith] a whole year to weave it. It's brand new and made of all-natural dyes." Each of those four points turned out to be not negatives, but untrue.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: With a handle like yours, I'm guessing you know that all the best Persian rugs *must* have a "flaw" of some kind (to avoid implying that the carpet-weaver's skills might eclipse those of his deity). So arguably if your rug had ***four*** "descriptive shortcomings", you got a real bargain (unless you failed miserably in the "haggling" phase, and agreed to give the seller all your money *and* your first-born child! :)

Comment: "rug merchant" may be an ethnic slur, as carpet salesmen are stereotypically associated with the middle east. It definitely has the connotations of a disreputable salesman, but possibly a racial aspect too.